# How to override grub and boot to Ubuntu directly (from UEFI or windows)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently changed the grub parameters to this (via grub manager):

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
```

because I wanted GRUB to shows only if I pressed shift and I wanted my pc to automatically boot to windows if I didn't press anything.

Unfortunately I can't display GRUB by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> on start, my pc automatically boot to windows and I can't go back to Ubuntu to change the setting.

(It's normal that it boot to windows automatically because I specified it in the GRUB settings)

Do you know a way to either access grub or access Ubuntu ?

I tried to boot override from UEFI to Ubuntu but I still go to windows...

Thank you.

Comment: UEFI uses escape key not shift that BIOS uses. So if UEFI boot try Escape key.

Comment: Actually, the key used to access EFI/UEFI boot options is ***NOT*** standardized. Common options include Esc, Enter, and various function keys (especially F2, F10, and F11, but sometimes something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to install a Windows program to access Linux partitions from within Windows as described here: ([Best way to access ext partion in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/717642/best-way-to-access-ext-partion-in-windows))

The next step is to edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and search for `timeout` changing the value from `0` to `5`.

Save the file and reboot.

Note that after rebooting Ubuntu you still need to change `/etc/default/grub` otherwise the next time you run `sudo update-grub` the timeout will go back to zero.

Comment: @Tom23 Glad to hear it. Don't forget to check the answer as the solution so others know it will work for them too.